# How to create a custom styled select box for WordPress Category widget and Archive widget

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, select, wordpress-theming

I have managed to create custom select boxes for WordPress Archive and Category widgets using [this code from codepen](http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz). Its works great on all browsers except that the links don't work as expected, i.e. when an option is selected, it should take you to the category page using the link in the option.

Below is the WordPress *select* code by default:

```
<div id="categories-2" class="widget_categories widget">
    <div class="widgettitle">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
    </div>
    <select name="cat" id="cat" class="postform">
        <option value="-1">Select Category</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="10">Education&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="8">Entertainment&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="11">Finance&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

The following is the WordPress *select* code after adding [the JavaScript code from codepen](http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz)

```
<div id="categories-2" class="widget_categories widget">
    <div class="widgettitle">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="select">
        <select name="cat" id="cat" class="postform select-hidden">
            <option value="-1">Select Category</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="10">Education&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="8">Entertainment&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="11">Finance&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</option>
        </select>
        <div class="select-styled">"Select Category"</div>
            <ul class="select-options" style="display: none;">
                <li rel="-1">Select Category</li>
                <li rel="10">Education&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</li>
                <li rel="8">Entertainment&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</li>
                <li rel="11">Finance&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the JavaScript code I used changed option tags `<option>`  to `<li>` tags and `value=""` to `rel=""`. Below is the JavaScript code that does the changes.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        //console.log($this.val());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

I am not a JavaScript expert, I need someone to help me change the code so that the links selected in the select box take you to the referred category or archive page.